# Grails String with html code breaking javascript(cordova)

Tags: javascript, grails, cordova

In my grails application I have this String

```
String description = "<p>Some long description here that shows me the message in javascript</p><span data-icon=\"pushpin\"><p>But here doesnt give me any message in javascript"</p>
```

But when I try to recover the String to do an alert or something in javascrip, in my cordova project:

```
var button = '<button type="button" onclick="getInfo("' + x.description + '")">More infomation</button>';`
```

It only gives me the me the first `<p></p>` and writes inside the button, I know its from the String `"pushpin"` but there's a way to fix the `""` or `''` ?

I'd like to not use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issues come from the fact the double/single quotes aren't escaped when the value is rendered. Try using the encodeAsJavascript() function. You may also want to read the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/security.html) about this.

```
x.description.encodeAsJavaScript()
```

Or in the controller (since you aren't using GSP)

```
def String description = "<p>Some long description here that shows me the message in javascript</p><span data-icon=\"pushpin\"><p>But here doesnt give me any message in javascript</p>".encodeAsJavaScript()
```

Comment: Another thing, I'm not using gsp to render decode/encode parts. It's cordova(edited my question).

Comment: Then do the encoding in your controller.